# Why isn't my question labeled with "edited"?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question and after a minute I edited it. But the question doesn't say "edited x minutes ago" above my user card. What's the reason?

[image: Question]

Answer (score 7):

There is a 5 minute grace period after making a post and editing it where it doesn't show as a new edit. In the case of a new post it is included in the initial revision. In the case of an edit it is included in the edit history.

This is done to reduce the noise from a lot of tiny edits done in a short period of time.

[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

> #### Grace period
>
> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the
> revision history, a single user who makes a binding (not suggested)
> edit to a post is given a 5-minute [grace
> period](/tags/grace-period/info), *except* if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The previous revision was a rollback.
> - The new revision is a rollback (includes cases where one selects to edit a prior revision and doesn't make any changes).
> - The user does not have the [remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)
>   privilege.
>
> During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into
> the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final
> outcome of all their edits within that 5-minute period. The grace
> period ends after exactly 5 minutes, or if:
>
> - Another user edits the post, at which time *their* grace period begins.
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor (ignores deleted comments).
> - If the post being edited is a question and an answer has been added since the previous revision (ignores deleted answers but *does*
>   include answers by the editor).
> - The post is a question, and it has been closed since the previous revision.

Comment: So this differs from site to site. On other sites the posts are labeled "edited" even if the edits were minor and even if they were done just one second before.

Comment: @SnackExchange That is news to me, I don't know of any sites that do that and that sounds like a site by site override from the defaults.

Comment: @SnackExchange As quoted in the answer, the five-minute grace period doesn't apply if your reputation is below a certain amount. It's likely that the sites where that's happening are the sites where (excluding the association bonus) you have less than 10 rep.

Comment: @F1Krazy What's the reason the five-minute grace period applies if reputation is above a certain amount, but doesn't apply in the opposite case?

Comment: @SnackExchange 10 reputation isn't hard for people to get which is all it takes to get rid of the new user restrictions. Just 2 votes on a question or 1 vote on an answer.

Comment: @JoeW But both the votes on a question and on an answer value 10 reputation.

Comment: @SnackExchange Okay, from my memory that didn't used to be the case but the point still stands and it is even easier for new users to hit 10 rep and start having the 5 minute grace period.